# Store uptimes in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to monitor some websites from my server. Up- and down-times are stored in a database.

At the moment my table looks like this:

```
id (INT)

website_id (INT) 

uptime (DATETIME) 

downtime (DATETIME) 

lastState (INT)
```

The lastState stores the last HTTP-StatusCode

My Website No 5 eg has the following entries:

```
+----+------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | website_id | up                  | down                | lastState | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  5 |          5 | 2018-04-26 13:56:09 | 2018-04-27 10:42:14 |       503 | 2018-04-26 11:56:09 | 2018-04-26 11:56:09 |
| 13 |          5 | 2018-04-27 10:50:06 | 2018-05-10 08:32:13 |       503 | NULL                | NULL                |
| 20 |          5 | 2018-05-10 08:40:06 | 2018-05-14 03:02:14 |       503 | NULL                | NULL                |
| 23 |          5 | 2018-05-14 03:10:06 | NULL                |       301 | NULL                | NULL                |
+----+------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

I check the sites every 10 Minutes and when a host is down a new entry is created. I think (or better I hope) that this makes sense.

My only problem with this kind of data storage is that I want to calculate the uptime percentage. I think with pure SQL its not possible.

Please share your ideas with me. 
Thanks!

Comment: If you store each ping you do as a new row, simply as "site X responded with code Y at time Z", then it's pretty simple to calculate some statistics based on that information…

Comment: I thought about this when I was starting this project. I monitor about 100 websites (and growing). So it would be about 15000 lines a day in the database and about 500.000 each month. I wanted to keep the database small and quick.

Comment: 500k is virtually nothing for a properly set up database, you can trim and consolidate information after a while if that really becomes an issue, and it's usually better to *have data* than not to and later figure out that you've been discarding needed information.

Comment: I would like to figure out something to compute the uptime: when a host is down, you create a new record, but you seem also to UPDATE the `down` column of the latest row for that website, is that correct?

Comment: @ThomasG Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Thta's a very good system and yes you can calculate your uptime from it in SQL. I will cook you this

Comment: could you provide more info on the columns created_at and updated_at?

Comment: They are not needed (and not used). They are created automatically by my PHP framework (Laravel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your log system is pretty well done, it is "easy" to compute the website uptime from your logs, in pure SQL

Here's a way to do it . It will work on any recent version of MySQL. If you run the latest version (8), there is an alternative way to do it, with less instructions, using new windowing functions

I decompose each step. (Note that I named your table `monitoring`)

---

First we want to gather on the same row, the uptime and downtime of *concurrent* logs for the same website:

```sql
    SELECT m.website_id, m.uptime, m.downtime, m.lastState ,
            COALESCE((
                SELECT uptime
                FROM monitoring mold
                WHERE  m.downtime < mold.uptime AND mold.website_id=m.website_id
                GROUP BY website_id
            ), NOW()) AS lastuptime
    FROM monitoring m
```

Returns

```
| website_id |               uptime |             downtime | lastState |           lastuptime |
|------------|----------------------|----------------------|-----------|----------------------|
|          5 | 2018-04-26T13:56:09Z | 2018-04-27T10:42:14Z |       503 | 2018-04-27T10:50:06Z |
|          5 | 2018-04-27T10:50:06Z | 2018-05-10T08:32:13Z |       503 | 2018-05-10T08:40:06Z |
|          5 | 2018-05-10T08:40:06Z | 2018-05-14T03:02:14Z |       503 | 2018-05-14T03:10:06Z |
|          5 | 2018-05-14T03:10:06Z |               (null) |       301 | 2018-05-15T14:19:06Z |
```

Notice that the `lastuptime` column is always the same as the `uptime` of the next row for the same website. If there's no "next" then it means that the website is up, so we take NOW() as the reference datetime.

---

Next, with the above query, we can easily make in-row computing to measure the time difference (in second) between uptimes and downtimes

```sql
SELECT 
       mm.*,
       TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(COALESCE(downtime, NOW()), uptime)) AS uptime_seconds, 
       TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(lastuptime, COALESCE(downtime, NOW()))) AS downtime_seconds
FROM
(
    SELECT m.website_id, m.uptime, m.downtime, m.lastState ,
            COALESCE((
                SELECT uptime
                FROM monitoring mold
                WHERE  m.downtime < mold.uptime AND mold.website_id=m.website_id
                GROUP BY website_id
            ), NOW()) AS lastuptime
    FROM monitoring m
) mm
```

Returns

```
| website_id |               uptime |             downtime | lastState |           lastuptime | uptime_seconds | downtime_seconds |
|------------|----------------------|----------------------|-----------|----------------------|----------------|------------------|
|          5 | 2018-04-26T13:56:09Z | 2018-04-27T10:42:14Z |       503 | 2018-04-27T10:50:06Z |          74765 |              472 |
|          5 | 2018-04-27T10:50:06Z | 2018-05-10T08:32:13Z |       503 | 2018-05-10T08:40:06Z |        1114927 |              473 |
|          5 | 2018-05-10T08:40:06Z | 2018-05-14T03:02:14Z |       503 | 2018-05-14T03:10:06Z |         325328 |              472 |
|          5 | 2018-05-14T03:10:06Z |               (null) |       301 | 2018-05-15T14:23:16Z |         126790 |                0 |
```

We can already notice from those results that your downtime is mostly always the same (472 or 473 seconds).

---

The final step is to compute the total seconds of downtime and uptime for each website, and to determine the percentage of uptime

```sql
SELECT website_id, 
       SUM(uptime_seconds) AS uptime_seconds, 
       SUM(downtime_seconds) AS downtime_seconds,

       (100 - SUM(downtime_seconds)/SUM(uptime_seconds)*100) AS pourc_uptime
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
           mm.*,
           TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(COALESCE(downtime, NOW()), uptime)) AS uptime_seconds, 
           TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(lastuptime, COALESCE(downtime, NOW()))) AS downtime_seconds
    FROM
    (
        SELECT m.website_id, m.uptime, m.downtime, m.lastState ,
                COALESCE((
                    SELECT uptime
                    FROM monitoring mold
                    WHERE  m.downtime < mold.uptime AND mold.website_id=m.website_id
                    GROUP BY website_id
                ), NOW()) AS lastuptime
        FROM monitoring m
    ) mm
 ) mmm
GROUP BY website_id
```

Returns

```
| website_id | uptime_seconds | downtime_seconds | pourc_uptime |
|------------|----------------|------------------|--------------|
|          5 |        1641971 |             1417 |      99.9137 |
```

---

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/79a578/39)

So this only show the results for 1 website and a few logs (that you posted), but I am confident that it should run fine against your whole table, even if you have 1 million rows

You should create some VIEWS out of these queries to make your life easier.

Comment: This is a very good and very detailed answer. Thank you very much for this great piece of information. :) I have to admit that my SQL knowledge ends up using simple joins.

Comment: Just to add a gotcha to this answer - you shouldn't divide downtime by uptime to get the uptime%, you need to divide downtime by the number of seconds it was available to be up (not how much it was actually up for - otherwise the downtime could be higher than the uptime and you can end up with a negative %!)